# What is the use of "on" after a time?

Tags: prepositions

[source](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/blogs-china-blog-44000069)

> Three weeks **on** from its debut in April, the film’s domestic gross box
>   office had barely surpassed $600,000 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It emphasises the period of time that has elapsed. There's not a significant difference between "three weeks from its debut" and "three weeks on from its debut", but the "on" gives a sense that something would have been expected to change in that length of time.

[A period of time] + on can also be used by itself. Such as "What has the film grossed three weeks on?" would mean essentially the same as "what has the film grossed after three weeks have passed?"